# Avoiding image upload on a refresh

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I am working with the simplest form of image-uploading possible, and I would very much like to keep it that way, with just  and some php.

The code looks like this

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" value="Upload image">
</form>

<?php
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image'][tmp_name]));
mysql_query("INSERT INTO store_images VALUES ('','$image')");
?>
```

I select an image, upload it and hit refresh once/twice. When I take a look at the table "store_images", the image has been uploaded twice/thrice/etc.

How do I avoid that, without ruining the option of uploading another image?

Comment: Once uploaded do a redirect to the form page or another page to stop the user being able to resubmit the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with:

Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Now for your problem:

You should do a redirect after the successful upload of the image `header('Location: http://example.com/the/address')`. This can even be the same page. Because you do a redirect the data isn't on the page anymore and won't be inserted again.

Answer (score 2):

Generate a random number, hash or similar with the Form and insert it into the Database together with your image. Check the database for existing hash before insert.

Comment: While OP should definitely design the app so that if the user does re-post the image, it doesn't get stored a second time, it's better if the UI also redirects the browser so that the image isn't reposted in the first place.

Comment: +1 because my form handler does not trigger until after some content has been echo'd, so I can't use `header` as instructed by the accepted answer. I thus can't redirect as indicated by the above comment unless I want to do an **UGLY** `JS` redirect.

Answer (score 0):

check the value of `$image` first in db and only if it is not there , upload/insert

Answer (score -1):

If you want no file duplicates in your table (which is advisable) then create an [md5 hash of the file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php) and store it in a column with the file and make the md5 column unique.

If you do want file duplicates in your table then do the exact same thing as above only make the md5 column and the filename unique. This should allow a different user to insert the very same picture again with a different name.

If you want file duplicates with the same name to be allowed then do what @jimpic suggested. This should allow you or any other user to insert duplicates of the same file with the same file name but only if you do it on purpose.

Don't redirect to another page after every insert. It's better not to brake the normal browser back/forward functionality if you can. To the user it feels like one page refresh when in fact to the browser they would behave like 2 and annoy people because the back button would ask "do you want to resend the form data".

Comment: Huh?  "because the back button would ask "do you want to resend the form data"." That's exactly why you do a redirect. To prevent it...

Comment: You do a redirect to prevent the **refresh** button from reinserting the new data. But now the **back** button will be doing the reinserting. Genius isn't it? Run away from a problem instead of fixing it.

Comment: The best most reliable and versatile solution is the one with the random hash stored in a column of the table and passed along with the form.

Comment: My other solutions are more rigid and need you to be sure the application's needs can't go outside the normal usecases.

Comment: If you do try the reinsert when using a random hash or the md5  and it fails due to unique constraints you have a reasonable error message you can present to the user.

Comment: "But now the back button will be doing the reinserting." --> wrong

Comment: Have you ever used phpmyadmin (before the ajaxification an even now in some situations). Have you noticed that when you execute an SQL query it redirected you to the results page and if you hit back it'd ask if you want to "resend the post data" (action which would trigger the reexecution of the query)? And you always have to hit back twice or open the dropdown of previous pages and select the second in the list to get back to the page with the SQL query you just executed.

Comment: No I have never used phpmyadmin. I never needed it. And frankly I don't care what phpmyadmin screws up. Doing a redirect after a successful form submit is best practice / standards. And if done right prevents everything you are talking about. I suggest you [read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) into stuff like this before posting comment after comment.

Comment: I know about PRG being a design pattern. I just happen to not agree that it's the best/safest way to accomplish what is needed. In a REST architecture for example PRG is part of the whole philosophy and I accept it due to it's purpose there. I just don't think redirecting in this case is mandatory.